# Erlang supervision and applications

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

I have number of supervised components that can stand alone as separate applications. But I would like to cascade them such that a call or event in a worker in one component starts the next component down in an inverted tree-like structure.

1) Can I package each of these components as separate applications? 
2) If so,how do I write the calling code to start the child application?
3) Or do I need to do something else altogether and,if so, what?

Note: I'm still working on mastery of supervision trees. The chain of events following application:start(Mod) is still not burned well into my head.

Many thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Supervision trees** and **applications** are complex Erlang/OTP concepts. They are both documented in [OTP Design Principles User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/users_guide.html) and in particular in:

- chapter 5: [Supervisor behaviour](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html)
- chapter 7: [Applications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html).

**Supervision trees are not dependency trees** and should not be designed as such. Instead, a supervision tree should be defined based on the desired crash behavior, as well as the desired start order. As a reminder, every process running long enough must be in the supervision tree.

An **application** is a reusable component that can be started and stopped. Applications can depend on other applications. However, applications are meant to be started at boot-time, and **not when an event occurs**.

**Processes can be started when a given event occurs**. If such processes shall be supervised, simply call `supervisor:start_child/2` on its supervisor when the event occurs. This will start the process and it will be inserted in the supervision tree. You will typically use a [Simple-one-for-one supervisor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id72445) which will initially have no child.

Consequently:

1. You can package components as separate applications. In this case, you will declare the dependencies of applications in each application's [app(4)](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/app.html) file. Applications could then only be started in the proper order, either with a boot script or interactively with `application:start/1`.
2. You can package all your components in a single application and have worker processes starting other worker processes with [`supervisor:start_child/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2).
3. You can package components as separate applications and have worker processes in one application starting processes in another application. In this case, the best would be to define a module in the target application that will call [`supervisor:start_child/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2) itself, as applications should have clean APIs.

When you have worker processes (parents) starting other worker processes (children), you probably **will link those processes**. Linking is achieved with [`link/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#link-1). Links are symmetric and are usually established from the parent since the parent knows the pid of the child. If the parent process exits abnormally, the child will be terminated, and reciprocally.

Links are the most common way to handle crashes, for example a child shall be terminated if the parent is no longer there. Links are actually the foundation of OTP supervision. Adding links between worker processes reveals that designing supervision trees is actually difficult. Indeed, with links, you will have both processes terminating if one crashes, and yet, you probably do not want the child process to be restarted by the supervisor, as a supervisor-restarted child process will not be known (or linked) to a supervisor-restarted parent process.

If the parent shall terminate when the child exits normally, then this is a **totally different design**. You can either have the child send a message to the parent (e.g. return a result) or the parent monitor the child.

Finally, the parent process can terminate a child process. If the child is supervised, use [`supervisor:terminate_child/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#terminate_child-2). Otherwise, you can simply send an exit signal to the child process. In either cases, you will need to unlink the child process to avoid an exit of the parent process.

Both [links](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id83047) and [monitors](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id83222) are documented in the [Erlang Reference Manual User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/users_guide.html). Instead of monitors, you might be tempted to trap exits, something explained in [the guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id83112). However, the manual page for the function to achieve this ([process_flag/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_flag-2)) specifically reads:

> Application processes should normally not trap exits.

This is typical OTP design wisdom, spread here and there in the documentation. Use monitors or simple messages instead.

Comment: Many thanks, Paul. Yes, when I read the references they seem simple enough, but when I try to put them to practice... Anyway, I have components A, B, C... A has many processes created by a simple one-to-one supervisor, as do B, and C, etc. Each process in A has a selection device that enables the user of that process to select functionality in B, thus starting a process owned by B that terminates when the initiating process in A terminates. Perhaps the options in your response covers this case. But, sad to say, it's still not clear to me. Thanks again, LRP

Comment: Assume, I might add, that we have many users, each traversing down his/her own instance of the tree. (I'm beginning to suspect that this case is harder to describe than do.) Thanks, L.

Comment: You need option 2 or 3. Split in applications is irrelevant here. If by "when process in A terminates" you mean **crashes**, you need to link the processes. If you mean **terminates gracefully**, then the process from A simply needs to terminate the child process from B. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I'll try some Tinkertoy code to see if I understand.